# How do I get my web server to serve via a public ip?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox

So I recently setup a Ubuntu server 16.04 web server on VirtualBox(main/host computers OS is windows 10). When I type in the servers local IP it brings me to the apache/ubuntu default web page which is good. But when I type in my routers public IP it won't load and I already setup port forwarding on my router (see pics below). So like I said the server works locally and I setup port forwarding so I really don't see what the problem could be unless I didn't setup port forwarding right which I think I did. Thanks in advance!

[image: First_picture]

[image: Second_picture]

Comment: Did you set up port forwarding in VirtualBox?

Comment: Do you mean that it times out/refuses the connection from the public IP, or do you just get a "410: Gone" error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with that brand of router. Port forwarding looks correct. I suggest checking your UFW rules on your server. You can run this command to allow traffic destined for port 80 in UFW

`sudo ufw allow 80`

If you're still having issues, try disabling UFW, and see if you can access it.

`sudo ufw disable`

Comment: I tried it and i still couldnt connect i couldnt connect on port 21 for filezilla  too. So what other problems do you think it could be? Thanks for your response tho!

Comment: i tried the ufw disable and it didnt work